# Issue with WordPress - Slider Revolution not uploading on the page upon site reload

Tags: wordpress, slider-revolution

Can you help me with resolving an issue on my WordPress site? When loading the site, all sections below the Slider Revolution appear automatically, but the slider section doesn't display immediately. It requires scrolling or hovering the mouse over the slider area.

This issue is replicated across the other pages on my site.